# PHP move_uploaded_file multiple paths

Tags: php

I am working on an upload page. I need to send the same file upload (from the user) to various different paths for display.

The following work to upload the file to a single path:

```
    if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $filepath)){
    //Do something
}
```

Using move_uploaded_file I have tried the following but did not work:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, ($filepath, $anotherfilepath))){
//Do something
} 


if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $filepath)){
//Do something
}
if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $anotherfilepath)){
//Do something
}

if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $filepath) &&     (move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $anotherfilepath)){
//Do something
}
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: use move_uploaded_file() once and when success then use copy()

Comment: Your requirement is copying not moving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $new_dest)){
    //moved to destination, now copy
    copy($new_dest, $another_new_dest);
}
```

if you need it to copy to more then one other

```
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $new_dest)){
    //moved to destination, now copy
    copy($new_dest, $another_new_dest);
    copy($new_dest, $yet_another_new_dest);
    //and so on...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to upload one single file to the server and to make it available on multiple paths via `.htaccess`. Something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/my-first-custom-path/(.*)$ /my-private-upload-directory/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/my-second-custom-path/(.*)$ /my-private-upload-directory/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now, instead of accessing `http://my-site.com/my-private-upload-directory/my-file.pdf` you will be able to download the file from both paths `http://my-site.com/my-first-custom-path/my-file.pdf` and `http://my-site.com/my-second-custom-path/my-file.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

move_uploaded_file will move the file, and not copy it -- which means it'll work only once.

i think you should user copy function after first copy like:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc,$filepath)){
//Do something
} 
if(copy($filepath, $filepath)){
//Do something
}
if(copy($filepath, $anotherfilepath)){
//Do something
}
```